# Absolute bottom positioning in relative div

Tags: css, positioning

I want to position "rightBottomPart" to the bottom of "rightPart" and I want "rightPart to be as high as "leftPart". The problem is that I don't know the height of the content in "leftPart" and therefore I can't set the height of "text". (Height in "text" would solve it)

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

and I want it to look like this:

[image]

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <div id="headers" style="background-color: Olive; width: 300px; height: 50px;"></div>
    <div id="text" style="background-color: Navy; position: relative; width: 300px;">
        <div id="leftPart" style="background-color: Gray; width: 200px; float: left;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        <div id="rightPart" style="background-color: Red; float: right;">
                <div id="rightTopPart" style="background-color: Lime; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;">top</div>
                <div id="rightBottomPart" style="background-color: Yellow; position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">bottom</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks right in IE7, but not in the rest of the browsers I've tested. If I remove the DOCTYPE-tag it also looks good in IE8, but still not in Google Chrome.

What am I missing?

Thanks
Carl

Comment: A super suggestion: instead of using the `style` attribute in html. Have everything contained in a so-called style sheet. use: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" type="text/css" media="all" />`

Comment: Yeah, I do, but for this example I thought this way would give fewer code lines to insert in my question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep floats and position under control, you need to keep two things in mind: the position is absolute according to its parent element and usually needs dimensions, and floated objects do not have dimensions by default.

Since your test represents a simple two-column model, have a look at this nice overview here, it might clarify things up a little bit: [equal height columns with css](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

So, the trick here  is to give #text a float and pos:rel and then the #right*Part will know where they are positioned.

Have a look here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>

<style>
body             { margin: 0; }
#headers         { background: Olive; width: 300px; height: 50px; }
#text            { background: Navy; position: relative; width: 300px; display: block; float:left; }
#leftPart        { background: Gray; width: 200px; float: left;  display: inline-block; }
#rightPart       { background: Red; }

#rightTopPart    { background: Lime;     position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; }
#rightBottomPart { background: Yellow;  position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
</style>                                 

</head>
<body>
    <div id="headers"></div>
    <div id="text">
        <div id="leftPart">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        <div id="rightPart">
                <div id="rightTopPart">top</div>
                <div id="rightBottomPart">bottom</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Kind regards, mtness

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't need the float when I'm using absolute positioning.

Thanks!!
Carl